# derivation in ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

From the book of Kaplansky, A derivation of a ring $R$ is an additive mapping $r\rightarrow r'$ of $R$ ino itself satisfying $(ab)'=a'b+ab'$. We write $a'',a''',...,a^{(n)}$ for the successive derivatives.

Then, may I say, a derivation is only a differential function which satisfy additive endomorphism and Leibnitz's rule?

then, how if the derivative of an element of a ring does not exist? or how if the derivatives of an element of a ring is not in the ring itself?

notice Lie product, if a derivation $d$ in ring $R$ satisfy $d([x,y])=[x,y]$, it means $d$ satisfy additive endomorphism and $d(xy)=d(x)y+xd(y)$ for all $x,y \in R$ plus additional property which is $d[x,y]=d(xy-yx)=[x,y]=xy-yx$, right?

as usual, any comment and answer will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A derivation of $R$ in itself is by definition a *map* $R\to R$ which, as you said, is a group homomorphism satisfying the Leibniz rule.

Note that such a map always exists (take the zero map for example). Existence of further non trivial derivations is I guess what you are asking about when you say "what if the derivative of an element of $R$ does not exist". But note that the term "derivative of an element" without mentioning the derivation (the map) does not make sense in general: $R$ is just an abstract ring.

This is a particular case of a more general notion, namely the notion of an $A$-derivation of an $A$-algebra $B$ into a $B$-module $M$. This is just an $A$-linear map which satisfies the Leibniz rule. In your case, $A=\mathbb{Z}$ and $B=M=R$.

This notion is closely related to the notion of **Kähler differentials**, which is an algebraic analog (and in fact a generalization) of the notion of differential used to define tangent spaces in smooth manifolds.

Comment: Oh i see now. About "what if the derivative of an element of R does not exist", then if such mapping $d$ exists, then it can't be called derivation because it doesn't satisfy definition, is it right? I'm sorry, but i dont get part "In your case, $A=\mathbb{Z}$ and $B=M=R$.

Comment: Such a mapping $d$ is by definition what we call a derivation. The term derivative of an element of a ring is (in general) meaningless, you can give it a meaning through such a derivation map $d$. And regarding that last part, if you are not familiar with modules and algebras, you can just ignore it. But if you know the definitions, then it is good to recognize the definition you have seen as a particular case of that more general definition. And the way to recognize it is with those assignations (note that a $\mathbb{Z}$-linear map is just a group homomorphism)

Comment: I get it now. The term derivative of an element of a ring is useless, unless we define a mapping (derivation) $d$ in the ring itself. Yeah, i'm not familiar with module and algebra now, but i must force myself to be familiar with from now. Any advise for the book module and algebra including derivation in it? Really, Big Thank for You!!!

Comment: Atiyah-Macdonald, Introduction to Commutative Algebra (for modules and algebras) and Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry II.8 or Liu's Algebraic geometry and arithmetic curves for derivations. Do you want me to include anything else on the answer? (Because it seems that you didn't accept it so far)

Comment: I'm sorry, i didn't mean it! I just forgot to click the button. I'm already accept your answer, but if you want to include anythng else on the answer like you said, i'm very welcome to it! Really, thank you so much!

Comment: No problem! Glad to help :)