# Closed form for a differential recurrence

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials, recurrence-relations

Function $d_0$ is given, $d_{n+1}(y)=d_n'(y)d(y)$ for every $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ (apostrophe means differentiation).

Can we write a closed formula (or at least an explicit sum) for:

1. $d_n(y)$?
2. $d_0(y)+d_1(y)t+d_2(y)t^2+\dots+d_n(y)t^n$?

Comment: What is $d(y)$ in your recursion formula?

Comment: In fact $d$ is a function from topological vector space to topological vectors space (as I try to be the most general), but it seems the result would be the same as if $d$ were just a real function

Comment: Do you know anything about $d_0$ and $d$? E.g. are they polynomials, etc.?

Comment: @weee No, $d$ are arbitrary functions

Comment: Well, at least you need to impose some regularity otherwise the derivatives might not exist for arbitrary $n$. A sufficient condition would be, that $d,d_0\in C^\infty$ on some domain.

Comment: In general, we cannot multiply functions between (topological ) vector spaces $V$ and $W$. On the other hand, even more general suitable notion is a [derivation in a ring](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2685055/derivation-in-ring). But even for 1, a formula expressing $d_n$ by $d_0$ and $d$ seems to be complicated.